# Extract keys from JavaScript object and use as variables

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, extract

There is a method in PHP called `extract` which does exactly what I want to do here. Say I have an object that looks like this:

```
var data = {
    name: "Olly"
    age: 19
};
```

I want to run a method like `extract(data)` so that I can then access the properties in that object by just using `name` and `age`, instead of `data.name` and `data.age`.

I've done a bit of Googling and couldn't find anything.

Comment: Are you using a minifier or optimizer like Yahoo YUI or Google Closure?

Comment: I suppose Javascript's `with` statement is more closely similar to PHP's `extract` method. That being said, `with` is not very common and I would not use it unless you truly understand how it works. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with

Comment: @KrisKrause No, I am not. Why do you ask?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
function myTestFunction() {
    var data = {
        name: "Olly",
        age: 19,
    };
    for (var key in data) {
        this[key] = data[key];
    }
    alert(name +" is "+ age +"!");
}
myTestFunction();
```

(Try that here: http://jsfiddle.net/dHDxd/3/)

Or even export them to global namespace, by using `window[key] = data[key]`.
In any case, be very very careful with that, since the risk of clobbering the global namespace / override other stuff / etc. is very high.

### Update: general-purpose `extract()`

```
function extract(data, where) {
    for (var key in data) {
        where[key] = data[key];
    }
}

function runTest() {
    var myData = { name: "Olly", age: 19, };
    extract(myData, this);
    alert(name +" is "+ age +"!");
}

runTest();
```

Comment: Updated to fix naming: it's called `extract()`, not `export()` :)

Comment: By saying this[key] = data[key] in a function aren't you *already* clobbering the global object?  Also note that `this` will be undefined in strict mode in that function, and will therefor throw an error

Comment: Yep, if you're running that from a function in the global namespace, you're right.. It would be better to run that from an object instance method or so, or not use it at all; but since he asked "how to do this.."

Comment: Well, +1, but passing in a context like that is corny, isn't it?  Why not keep the `this` like you had, and then call the function with `call`, and specify the `this` value that way?

Comment: it will just add the variables to global object (window)

Answer (score 1):

Here is more generic/multi-level/recurrent namespace extractor :)

```
function extract(rootObject, key) {
    var parts = key.split('.');
    var currentKey = parts.shift();
    return parts.length > 0 ? extract(rootObject[currentKey], parts.join('.')) : rootObject[currentKey];
}

var myObject = { a: { b: { c: 7 }}};
console.log(extract(myObject, 'a.b.c'));
console.log(extract(myObject, 'a'));
```